# RivetsJS: Update model with jQuery-ui Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, rivets.js

I'm new in [rivets.js](/questions/tagged/rivets.js) and I love it! 
Very useful in micro sites or small code fragments when other complete frameworks such AngularJS are too heavy.

I can make it work in all cases except when the input values changes via jQuery Plugin, a Datepicker in this particular case.

```js
rivets.configure({ prefix: "data-rv", templateDelimiters: ['{{', '}}'] });
var $data = {CDP:null};

rivets.bind($("#toBind"), { data: $data }); 

function Datepicker(selector, context) {
            //
            $(selector, context).datepicker().keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                    $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
                }
            })
        }
        
$data.CDP = {LastDeliveryDate: "01/01/2015"};

Datepicker(".date");
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rivets/0.8.1/rivets.bundled.min.js"></script>
<div id="toBind">
  <input type="text" class="form-control date" id="txtDeliveryDate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" data-rv-value="data.CDP.LastDeliveryDate">
  <span id="showText">{{data.CDP.LastDeliveryDate}}</span>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sLdvegdo/2/

As you see, value changes using the Datepicker selection dont update the model, but manual input does.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because the `rv-value` binder works by listening to `input` event (`change` in older version)

You can fix this by manually triggering the event [onSelect](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) as shown below:

```js
rivets.configure({
  prefix: "data-rv",
  templateDelimiters: ['{{', '}}']
});
var $data = {
  CDP: null
};

rivets.bind($("#toBind"), {
  data: $data
});

function Datepicker(selector, context) {
  //
  $(selector, context).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
      $(this).trigger('input');
    }
  }).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
      $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
    }
  })
}

$data.CDP = {
  LastDeliveryDate: "01/01/2015"
};

Datepicker(".date");
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rivets/0.8.1/rivets.bundled.min.js"></script>
<div id="toBind">
  <input type="text" class="form-control date" id="txtDeliveryDate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" data-rv-value="data.CDP.LastDeliveryDate">
  <span id="showText">{{data.CDP.LastDeliveryDate}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a moron... I tried triggering the "input" event BUT listening element on "change".
Long time without using jQuery-ui... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

TJ is correct by manually triggering the 'input' event, however I used the onChange event in my datepicker and it works great. Maybe it can help someone.

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true, orientation: 'bottom' })
.on('changeDate', function () { $(this).trigger('input'); });
```